# How to retrieve IE7 Personal Certificates from full windows partition backup

Tags: windows, backup, export, certificate

Somehow in the process of exporting certificates I forgot to export bank certificate in IE7 on previous XP install. Now I have full disk image on bacula storage of previous install, is there any way I can access certificates  on filesystem and "export" them?

One way would be to copy whole backedup partition on some other laptop and try to export from running system, but that' s a pretty long shot.

**#1 EDIT:** Seems like I have found directory where certificates are stored:
Documents and Settings\\ApplicationData\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates

Now, what's left is to figure out how can be certificates copied from old system and imported into new Win XP install.

Answer (score 0):

If you setup a virtual machine and targeted the backup image as the hard drive for the VM then you should be able to run your old computer as a VM and access the system like normal.

As far as exporting the certificate it should be the same like how you did for the other ones.

Comment: So there is no way to retrieve it from filesystem itself?

Comment: Looks like you found the answer yourself, good going.